# Discord Bot sends multiple messages but I only want it to send one

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My Discord Bot is sending multiple messages but I just want it to send one message.

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content == "hello"){
        msg.channel.send('Hello!');
    }
})
```

Comment: It is listening to "message" event hence it will send "hello" to every message.

Comment: If you have multiple instances of the bot running, then each instance of the bot will reply.

Comment: Try closing your IDE and restarting the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes your bot send `Hello!` to *every* message, including the `Hello!` message your bot just sent. This means your bot will send `Hello!` to a message, receive the `Hello!` message it just sent, send another message, etc.

You probably want to ignore messages that your bot sent, or generally ignore messages from all bots:

```js
bot.on('message', msg=>{
  // Ignore messages from your bot
  if (msg.author.id === bot.user.id) return
  // Or ignore messages from all bots
  // if (msg.author.bot) return

  // rest of your code...
})
```